# Understanding inheritence and polymorphism in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

Suppose we have following inherit classes.

```
class A
{
public:
    void virtual show()
    {
        cout << "I am A\n";
    }
};

class B:public A
{
public:
    void show()
    {
        cout << "I am B\n";
    }
};

class C:public B
{
public:
    void show()
    {
        cout << "I am C\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    A *obj = new C();
    obj->show();

    return 0;
}
```

Without creating any other object, how can I call B class's show() function???

One way I know is to modify show() in class C to,

```
void show()
{
    B::show();
    cout << "I am c\n";
}
```

This will first call B's show function then it will print "I am C". But I don't want the show() in C to be executed at all. I want the B's show() to be executed directly.

Is it even possible? Can we do it using casting or something?

Remember I am not allowed to create any other object other then the one already created i.e. C in main().
I was asked this question at an interview today.

Thanks!

Comment: just take out show in class C. You will thus get B's show

Comment: There is nothing to indicate that an `obj` is a `B`, meaning you can't know that it has a `void B::show()`. If you know you need `obj` to be a kind of `B`, than it should be a pointer to `B`. It seems like a design error.

Comment: What do you mean to "be executed directly"? That it won't print "I am C" or that it must completely bypass the C::show() call and only call B::show()?

Comment: @Daniel it must completely bypass the C::show()...

Comment: I'm still confused to the purpose. Making no assumption there is a `B` in the inheritance chain, one would have to test it, which means something like `B *bptr = dynamic_cast<B*>(obj); if (bptr) bptr->B::show();`. If you can make the assumption a `B` is wedged in there somewhere, then it gets considerably easier.

Comment: @MuzahirHussain If I was asked that question in an interview, I would first ask "why?". It seems the question is asking to implement a solution to a design error and the correct solution would be to fix the design, not the implementation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can force static dispatching by specify the class:

```
int main()
{
    A *obj = new C();
    static_cast<B*>(obj)->B::show();

    return 0;
}
```

But if you want to use this method, you must be sure that the object is indeed a `B` instance, otherwise it's undefined behavior.

Comment: This assumes we *know* `obj` is a kind of `B`. It's clear in this case, but it's not applicable in general.

Comment: I don't think it needs to be general, just work in this specific case. Plus, can't you just do `obj->B::show()` and skip the `static_cast` altogether?

Comment: @Daniel `obj` is a `A*` and `A` has no `void B::show()`, even if in this case the dynamic type would have it.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I added some additional note to the answer. I don't think there is a general way to do that.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux That's right, I was thinking it as a `C` when it is an `A`. My mistake

Comment: @liliscent The question was modified, and it looks like an interview question. So, without context, it's fair to assume a case-specific solution is fine.

Comment: @liliscent you could potentially write `if(B *b = dynamic_cast<B*>(obj)) { b->B::show()}`, which would only execute if obj were a `B` or higher

Comment: @Daniel Agree. This is one way among others, the key point is to ensure the type is indeed correct.